# Set new layout in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to change the layout of a fragment during runtime under a particular condition.

The initial layout in inflated within the onCreateView():

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.cancel_video, null);
    }
```

Then sometime later within the fragment code I would like to replace the initial layout with some other layout.

I've tried a few things so far; this is the latest that I have:

```
private void Something(){
    if(checkLicenseStatus(licenseStatus, statusMessage)){
                View vv = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.play_video, null);
                //more code
    }
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot replace the fragment's layout once it is inflated. If you need conditional layouts, then you either have to redesign your layout and break it down into even smaller elemens like `Fragments`. Alternatively you can group all the layout elements into sub containers (like `LinearLayout`), then wrap them all in `RelativeLayout`, position them so they overlay each other and then toggle the visibility of these `LinearLayout`s with `setVisibility()` when and as needed.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, I have done this in following way. When I need to set a new layout(xml), the following code snippet should be executed.

```
  private View mainView;

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup containerObject, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreateView(inflater, containerObject, savedInstanceState);

        mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null);
        return mainView;
  }

  private void setViewLayout(int id){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mainView = inflater.inflate(id, null);
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) getView();
    rootView.removeAllViews();
    rootView.addView(mainView);
  }
```

Whenever I need to change the layout I just call the following method

```
    setViewLayout(R.id.new_layout);
```

Comment: Getting `android.view.InflateException` when trying to `setViewLayout(R.id.new_layout)`

Comment: Can I see your code snippet and full error message?

Comment: This is exactly your code and this exception doesn't have any message, Android is sometimes weird :D BTW. I used other method to change layout in fragments

Answer (score 5):

Use a FragmentTransaction through the FragmentManger

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

if (fm != null) {
    // Perform the FragmentTransaction to load in the list tab content.
    // Using FragmentTransaction#replace will destroy any Fragments
    // currently inside R.id.fragment_content and add the new Fragment
    // in its place.
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_content, new YourFragment());
    ft.commit();
}
```

The code for the class YourFragment is just a LayoutInflater so that it returns a view

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment, container, false);

        return view;
    }   

}
```

Comment: This is replacing the entire fragment. I only desire to change the current fragment's layout.

Comment: Me too, I don't have any clue for that 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28271827/fragment-changing-xml-layout-not-working

Comment: @Dacto You have to replace the fragment, you cannot change the layout of a fragment from `onAttach()` to `onDetach()`

Answer (score 1):

I will change whole layout. You can change only a specific portion of your layout.

1. Add a root `FrameLayout` in `your_layout.xml`, it contains nothing.

   ```
   <FrameLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/fl_content"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />
   ```
2. Set your content in the java code.

   ```
   ViewGroup flContent = findViewById(R.id.fl_content);

   private void setLayout(int layoutId) {
       flContent.removeAllViews();
       View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutId, flContent, false);
       flContent.addView(view);
   }
   ```
3. You can change `layoutId` free at some point.
   If you have some listeners, you must set again.