# How to update a view from another layout in fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a text view in nav header of navigation drawer and i want want to set a text for it from fragment that has its own layout.

Comment: this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222925/set-new-layout-in-fragment

Comment: thanks i found my solution in this post

Comment: pleasure sir...

Answer (score 0):

Set the title using setTitle() from code.
If the textView is not title use `findViewById()` to get the reference of that view and update its text.